# ASP.NET MVC 4 IEnumerable<MyModel> Client side validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have main view and partial view:

//
    // GET: /Question/Add/

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    return View();
}

//
// Post: /Question/GetAnswerContainers/
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetAnswerContainers(int count)
{
    ViewBag.AnswerCount = count;
    return PartialView();
}
```

Main view is rather simple one:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add Question Form</legend>


        <div id="question_answers">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AnswerCount)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AnswerCount, 
              new {
                      @class = "answer_count", 
                      action = @Url.Action("GetAnswerContainers")
                  })<br/>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AnswerCount)<br/>

            <div id="answers"></div>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

Also I have jQuery for my text box:

```
$(function () {
    $('#question_answers input[type="text"].answer_count').keyup(function () {
        var answerCount = $(this).val();
        if (isNaN(answerCount))
            return;            

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: { count: $(this).val() },
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            timeout: 2000,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                removeAnswers();
                addAnswers(data);

                $('form').removeData('validator');
                $('form').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');
            },
            error: null
        });
    });
});

function addAnswers(data) {
    var answersContainer = $('#question_answers #answers');    
    answersContainer.append($((data)));
}
```

Partial view:

```
@model Quiz.Models.Question.QuestionAnswer

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AnswerText)
@for (var i = 0; i < ViewBag.AnswerCount; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AnswerText) 
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AnswerText)       
}
```

Model:

```
public class QuestionAnswer
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Answers")]
    public string AnswerText { get; set; } 
}
```

So my problem that standard asp.net client side validation can't handle with many object of QuestionAnswer model, it's take the first textBox from `for` loop and use it for validating all partial view.
Is it possible to validate many objects from one model in client side properly?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is with the name of the `AnswerText` textboxes. They all have the same name and the unobtrusive client side validation framework wouldn't how to which item to attach. So it simply attaches to the first one.

I would recommend you going through the [`following article`](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) in which Steven Sanderson illustrates a nice little helper called `Html.BeginCollectionItem` which is using Guids for the indexes of collection items. This would allow for the client side validation to work properly.